# NSUserDefault some times doesn't save itself

Tags: ios, save, nsuserdefaults

My app is getting bed reviews because users have to restore their purchase each time they enter the app... That drives me crazy because i don't have that problem on my iPhone. When transaction is made my app calls the following code:

```
[self.data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"fullBought"];
[self.data synchronize];
```

That's it! Then app checks `if([self.data objectForKey:@"fullBought"] != [NSNumber numberWithInt:1)`.

I tried to remove `[self.data synchronize]` but i even can't check the result because i don't have that problem!

Help me please to figure out the problem...

Comment: what is `self.data` ?

Comment: self.data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NSUserDefaults doesn't seem to be the issue.
You are comparing objects with "!=" operator in this instruction:

```
if([self.data objectForKey:@"fullBought"] != [NSNumber numberWithInt:1)
```

You should compare their value instead. With this operator, you are comparing memory addresses.
What you should do is:

```
if([[self.data objectForKey:@"fullBought"] intValue] != 1)
```

Comment: Would try it, i thing that's the solution. But why my code works on my device, and for users while they don't kill the app?

Comment: Thanks a lot ;) Forgot that i can't test... Would try to fined some people reporting about the problem and ask them to test for me.